# Mongoose aggregate by date and values

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I cannot solve a problem I am having on a project.

First of all, I have a Schema called Emotions, shown below:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const EmotionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  classification: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  probability: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});

export default mongoose.model('Emotion', EmotionSchema);
```

And some data like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "61144a393c532f066725bd24",
    "classification": "Feliz",
    "probability": 0.98,
    "user": "60eecfeba0810013e750cdbc",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-11T22:07:53.331Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-08-11T22:07:53.331Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "61144a46d30bd006fa2be702",
    "classification": "Feliz",
    "probability": 0.98,
    "user": "60eecfeba0810013e750cdbc",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-11T22:08:06.618Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-08-11T22:08:06.618Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "611541dd62a7f214afab3ceb",
    "classification": "Triste",
    "probability": 0.9,
    "user": "60eecfeba0810013e750cdbc",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-12T15:44:29.150Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-08-12T15:44:29.150Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "611541f762a7f214afab3cf5",
    "classification": "Raiva",
    "probability": 0.86,
    "user": "60eecfeba0810013e750cdbc",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-12T15:44:55.909Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-08-12T15:44:55.909Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "6115420362a7f214afab3cf7",
    "classification": "Neutro",
    "probability": 0.99,
    "user": "60eecfeba0810013e750cdbc",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-12T15:45:07.297Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-08-12T15:45:07.297Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "6115420462a7f214afab3cf9",
    "classification": "Neutro",
    "probability": 0.99,
    "user": "60eecfeba0810013e750cdbc",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-12T15:45:08.002Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-08-12T15:45:08.002Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "611543d252be9a187c380e5d",
    "classification": "Feliz",
    "probability": 0.91,
    "user": "60eecfeba0810013e750cdbc",
    "createdAt": "2021-08-12T15:52:50.599Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-08-12T15:52:50.599Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

What I want is:

First group each of these records by day.
Afterwards, count the values ​​by classification, but separating these classifications.

Something like that:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "12/08/2021",
    "feliz": 1,
    "triste": 1,
    "raiva": 1,
    "neutro": 2,
    "surpreso": 0,

  },
  {
    "_id": "11/08/2021",
    "feliz": 2,
    "triste": 0,
    "raiva": 0,
    "neutro": 0,
    "surpreso": 0,
  }
]
```

I did something like that, but it's only working for a value, eg "Feliz".
In code:

```
Emotion.aggregate([
      { $match: 
        {
          user: user._id,
          classification: "Feliz"
        }
      },
      { $group: {
        _id : { $dateToString: { format: "%d/%m/%Y", date: "$createdAt" } },
        feliz: { $sum: 1 }
      }},
    ], function(err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      return res.json(results);
    })
```

And it returns:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "12/08/2021",
    "feliz": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "11/08/2021",
    "feliz": 4
  }
]
```

One more question:
From the Client-side, I always get values ​​for "classification" like:
"Feliz", "Triste", "Surpreso", "Raiva", "Neutro".
So is it better to add an enum to my schema "Emotion"?

(Sorry for my English, i hope you understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by `createdAt` date and `classification`, count sum
- `$group` by `createdAt` only and construct the array of `classification` and `count` in key-value pair
- `$arrayToObject` to convert above key-value pair array of object to an object format

```
Emotion.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: {
      user: user._id,
      classification: "Feliz"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        createdAt: {
          $dateToString: {
            format: "%d/%m/%Y",
            date: "$createdAt"
          }
        },
        classification: "$classification"
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.createdAt",
      classifications: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.classification",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      classifications: {
        $arrayToObject: "$classifications"
      }
    }
  }
], 
function(err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  return res.json(results);
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RxdRlLNtClT)

> **Note:** this will not return classification when count is 0! You need to do this after query in js.

---

> *One more question: From the Client-side, I always get values ​​for "classification" like: "Feliz", "Triste", "Surpreso", "Raiva", "Neutro". So is it better to add an enum to my schema "Emotion"?*

It is up to your project requirement, you can set these values in enum to restrict the input.